# How should I interpret this sentence structure (with too many "or")?

Tags: meaning

> Without the written consent of us, you are not allowed to modify, use,
>   or allow others to use, rewrite, or disseminate the above content in
>   any way, or **use it for other commercial purposes.**

The bold part is confusing for me. This sentence is from a Service Agreement, and does the bold part mean:

> You are not allowed to use it for other commercial purposes.

or

> You are not allowed to allow others to use it for other commercial
>   purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the author of this statement meant that you, yourself, are not allowed to use "it" for other commercial purposes. One of the preceding clauses, "... or allow others to use" prohibits you from allowing *others* to use it *at all* (for *any* purpose).

On the other hand, if you skip over the parenthetical additions to the main sentence, it also contains a prohibition on "you" using the above content without written consent at all:

> "**Without the written consent of us, you are not allowed to** modify,
>   **use**, or allow others to use, rewrite, or disseminate **the above content in any way**, or use it for other commercial purposes.

Maybe the lawyers got a little tangled up in their own word game here.